# Graphically showing the same functions as the Brisk menu

Tags: 22.04, ubuntu-mate, panel-applets

I thought I had this issue solved.

My brisk menu keeps disappearing again.

If that can not be fixed, is there another way of graphically showing the same functions as the Brisk menu?

Comment: @I revised my post. @guiverc